# Is it correct to say ‘putting hope in you’?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, phrase-usage

Is it correct to say “putting hope in you”?
Should it have a pronoun in between?

Examples:

- Putting hope in you is the worst of plans.
- Putting **my** hope in you is the worst of plans.

I’m writing a song with it.
Is it correct if I leave it just like the first option? (Without ‘my’)

Comment: First and foremost, songs really do not walk on the path laid by Grammar. Being said that, you can use either version or a complete different one altogether. The main point is to devise lyrics that would fit the rhythm and the beat and the tune, and whatever else that good songs need to have in them....not grammar though. I hope this helps, and all the best!!

Comment: Thanks Dhanishtha! Good point about songs.